# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC IntelliJ + Maven

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to connect my java application to my sqlite database but I'm getting this good old error. I'm using Maven and my setup looks like this:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbNam.png)

I'm using IntelliJ and as far as I know Maven is well integrated. I'd like to know If I need to add the library somewhere else or put the jar file on the classpath.

I also leave here my pom.xml file with project definitions

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is my connection class:

```
package database;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Created by luiscosta on 3/29/17.
 */
public class DBConnection {

    private Connection conn;
    private String dbPath;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DBConnection(String name, String folder) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File dbDir = new File(folder);

        if (dbDir.isDirectory() && dbDir.exists()) { //confirms the database directory exists
            if (folder.charAt(folder.length() - 1) == '/') { //checks if the directory ends in /
                this.dbPath = folder + name;

            } else {
                this.dbPath = folder + '/' + name; //if not adds it in the end of the folder pah
            }


            //Connection

            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

                System.out.println("db Path" + this.dbPath);
                this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ChunkMetaData");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory not found!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you running the app? from the command line? from the IDE?

Comment: Seems Intellij is not downloading the jar for you. You can do mvn clean install from command line and try.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot, IntelliJ is looking *inside* the JAR file - you can't do that if it's not downloaded, surely?

Comment: Okay. I missed the project structure screenshot. Yes indeed it's there.

Comment: I'm running from the command line @Catchwa . Why?

Comment: I don't get why I'm having the problem. I downloaded it from Maven, it is placed correctly. I also control-clicked on `org.sqlite.JDBC` and it is getting the right repository. How can it complain about a not found class?!

Comment: @LuísCosta if you're running it from the command line then it'd be helpful to know what command you're typing

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you ever resolve this, Luis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using 3.15.1.

I had the same problem. I tried eclipse + maven / command line but ClassNotFoundException was thrown with 3.16.1. But with 3.15.1, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar into classpath. In Intellij, going to module settings you can add.  You can download from : https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/

I tried the below code and worked fine.

```
public class SqliteConnectionTry {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      connect();
  }

   public static void connect() {
      Connection conn = null;
      try {
          // db parameters
           String url = "jdbc:sqlite::memory";
          // create a connection to the database
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

           System.out.println("Connected!!");

         } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         } finally {
            try {
               if (conn != null) {
                  conn.close();
               }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If he's using Maven he shouldn't have to download anything manually

Comment: yes, it should work using maven and his pom looks good. But seems Intellij not downloading the jar in his case.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem (btw also happens with different drivers):

So the thing is that maven downloads the jar, but it does not put in your classpath

What I did in order to avoid to have to do this manually is packaging my application into a single jar -  driver included

I have done this with the plugin:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>path/to/MainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```